# Build a vector of results using a function and argument as data frame

Tags: r, function, lapply, sapply

Please advice which function (`map`/`lapply`/`sapply` ..) should I use if I have a function:

```
foo <- function(x, argument1 = "abc", default_score = def_score_dataframe)
returning score
```

Where `x` will be a data frame, argument1 will be changed each time I will run the function and default_score is a `data.frame` with: `name`, `default_score`,  in each row.

What I want is to use a one row function like `map`/`lapply` that will take a vector of values to assign to argument1 and to return a data frame with columns `argument1_Value` and `Score`

In other words something like this:

```
res_df <- lapply(argument_values,
                 foo(x, argument1 = argument_values, default_score = def_score_dataframe))
```

that should give me a result of:

```
res_df
# argument1_Value Score
#           "aaa"     5
```

Comment: Both, lapply as well a sapply are possible. See `lapply(1:10, function(x) x+1)` or `sapply(1:10, function(x) x+1)`. If you need help regarding your specific function you have to include the code and a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer your problem using an example.

You have a function that operates on a data frame `x`, a vector (`vectorArgument`) and another parameter (`exponent` with default 2)

```
myFun = function(x, vectorArgument, exponent = 2){
  z = (colSums(x) - vectorArgument) ^ exponent
}
```

If you apply this function to

```
df = data.frame(A = 1:4, B = 5:8)
d = myFun(df, c(1,22),3)

# You would get:
> d
A   B 
729  64
```

Now you have a set of `vectorArguments` in another data frame:

```
argumentsDF = data.frame(arg1 = c(1,22), arg2 = c(3,3), arg3 = c(17,21))
```

In order to calculate the above function on df and for each column (`margin = 2`) as the `vectorArgument` parameter, do:

```
result = apply(X = argumentsDF, 
           MARGIN = 2, 
           FUN = function(y){
             myFun(x = df,
                   vectorArgument = y,
                   exponent = 3)
             }
           )
```

You'll obtain:

```
> result
  arg1  arg2 arg3
A  729   343 -343
B   64 12167  125
```